# Flutter Choose text on image

Tags: flutter, mobile

Thank you for your comment.

Actually my code as following.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Myapp1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Myapp1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Myapp1State createState() => _Myapp1State();
}

class _Myapp1State extends State<Myapp1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {},
              child: FittedBox(
                  child: SizedBox(child: Image.asset("assets/test.png"))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
          painter: PathPainter(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.addRect(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size.width / 10, 305, size.width / 6, size.height / 20));

    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

When I run the code, the rectangle image is drawn hard on it.

When I click on A, I want to enclose option A in a rectangle, and when I click on B, I want to enclose option B in a rectangle.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkRRb.png)

Comment: Can you include your code that you've tried so far?

Comment: What you can do is wrap each radio button with a container  and provide the decoration property to it. In decoration provide border to it. Use setState of Stateful widget to change the border color from white to red.
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: myColor, //define this at top of your class, and change it in setState
          ),
        ),
        child: yourRadioButton(), //child should be your  single radio button
      )

Comment: There is a little trouble with red box alignment.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Don't think of the picture as a radio button. It just bulk imge.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
   List<String?> ischecked = [null, null, null, null];
```

Manage the state

**Widget**

```
List<String?> ischecked = [null, null, null, null];


class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  var _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          // direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Violet",
                title: "Violet",
                groupValue: ischecked[0],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = "Violet";
                    ischecked[1] = null;
                    ischecked[2] = null;
                  });
                }),
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Red",
                title: "Red",
                groupValue: ischecked[1],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = null;
                    ischecked[1] = "Red";
                    ischecked[2] = null;
                  });
                }),
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Yellow",
                title: "Yellow",
                groupValue: ischecked[2],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = null;
                    ischecked[1] = null;
                    ischecked[2] = "Yellow";
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomRadiobutton extends StatefulWidget {
  var value;

  var groupValue;

  var onChanged;

  var title;

  CustomRadiobutton(
      {Key? key, this.value, this.groupValue, this.title, this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomRadiobutton> createState() => _CustomRadiobuttonState();
}

class _CustomRadiobuttonState extends State<CustomRadiobutton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: widget.groupValue == null
            ? null
            : BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Radio(
                // title: Text(widget.title),
                value: widget.value,
                groupValue: widget.groupValue,
                onChanged: widget.onChanged),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0,right: 8.0),
              child: Text(widget.title),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SAmpleCode**  [Dartpad Live code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=fcd00eb3fd9fb4240693f1b7da0e574d)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Scanner'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

int myvalue = 0;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {}

  Future<int> functions() async {
    // do something here
    return Future.value();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Scanner"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

List<String?> ischecked = [null, null, null, null];


class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  var _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          // direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Violet",
                title: "Violet",
                groupValue: ischecked[0],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = "Violet";
                    ischecked[1] = null;
                    ischecked[2] = null;
                  });
                }),
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Red",
                title: "Red",
                groupValue: ischecked[1],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = null;
                    ischecked[1] = "Red";
                    ischecked[2] = null;
                  });
                }),
            CustomRadiobutton(
                value: "Yellow",
                title: "Yellow",
                groupValue: ischecked[2],
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    ischecked[0] = null;
                    ischecked[1] = null;
                    ischecked[2] = "Yellow";
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomRadiobutton extends StatefulWidget {
  var value;

  var groupValue;

  var onChanged;

  var title;

  CustomRadiobutton(
      {Key? key, this.value, this.groupValue, this.title, this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomRadiobutton> createState() => _CustomRadiobuttonState();
}

class _CustomRadiobuttonState extends State<CustomRadiobutton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: widget.groupValue == null
            ? null
            : BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Radio(
                // title: Text(widget.title),
                value: widget.value,
                groupValue: widget.groupValue,
                onChanged: widget.onChanged),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0,right: 8.0),
              child: Text(widget.title),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```